# Can I only trade with ambassadors?

Tags: gnomoria

I just started playing for the first time since they added ambassadors. My yaks died pretty early on and I wanted to buy new ones, but no traders have turned up. I invited some ambassadors but they require a bed before I can trade with them.. I need a bone needle to make beds, and I need yaks to make bone needles, so I can't trade with ambassadors. Spring and summer has gone by with no merchants appearing at my market stall, despite my kingdom having a worth of 5000. I had a market stall before day 5 of the first Spring, but nobody turned up. Are ambassadors the only way to trade now? If so, it seems I need to start a new save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ambassadors are also satisfied with simple straw beds, which you can build directly from the `Build->Furniture` menu with two units of straw. Should you have already fed all your straws to your animals, you can get more by farming wheat. Should you have no wheat seeds either, you need to kill *something* to get bone for a bone needle.

The wild animals which show up from time to time, like monitor lizards, honey badgers and bears, are surprisingly tough. When you attack them without properly trained and equipped soldiers, you will likely lose a few gnomes.

Answer (score 1):

user69964 was in the right directions. Aside from butchering your own animals, you can alternatively obtain bone by killing other animals or creatures.

Here's a list of bones provided per creature [per the wiki](http://www.gnomoriawiki.com/wiki/Butcher_Shop):

```
Yak             10
Alpaca          10
Emu             10
Honey Badger    10
Monitor Lizard  10
Bear            10
Goblin          ?
Ogre            0
Two-headed Ogre ?
```

Your militia might not really be up to the task, but killing a badger or lizard for their precious bone may be worth a few sacrifices.

Answer (score 0):

In order to attract merchants, you need to invite an ambassador and fulfill all their needs. Once you have a happy ambassador a merchant from their kingdom will arrive shortly after.

It seems like a sub question here is "How do I get a bone needle?" If you kill wild animals they will produce bones you can turn into needles after butchering. You can then create beds and satisfy the ambassador's needs.

Answer (score -1):

Go kill some goblins and take their bone! It's the only way I found to make the bone needle alternatively.

Comment: Goblins dont drop the kind of bones required for bone needles.